Пузырьковая сортировка, запись в файл csv
import random 

def bubble_sort(data): 
    iterations = 0 
    for i in range(len(data) - 1): 
       for j in range(len(data) - 1 - i): 
           if data[j] < data[j + 1]: 
               data[j], data[j + 1] = data[j + 1], data[j] 
               iterations += 1 
       return iterations 

def test_sorted(): 
    data = [random.randint(0, 1000) for i in range(100)] 
    data_to_sort = data.copy() 
    bubble_sort(data_to_sort) 
    if data_to_sort == sorted(data_to_sort, reverse=True): 
        print('OK') 
    else: 
        print('NOT OK') 

def make_observations(): 
    size = 10 
    results = [] 
    for i in range(100): 
        data = [random.randint(0, 1000) for i in range(size)] 
        results.append((size, bubble_sort(data))) 
        size += 10 
    return results 

def main(): 
    test_sorted() 
    with open('bubble.csv', 'w', newline='') as file: 
        file.write(f'size, iterations\n') 
        for row in make_observations(): 
            file.write(f'{row[0]}, {row[1]}\n') 
    print('Done!') 


if __name__ == '__main__': 
    main()

Не записывается файл csv.
Код выполняется но файл не записывается , не могу найти ни как где ошибка.

Записывается, только вы не знаете, куда именно. Укажите путь, например, d:\\bubble.csv

У меня файл записывается. Вангую, что вы ищете файл не в текущем каталоге выполнения скрипта (это может быть совсем не тот каталог, где расположен выполняемый скрипт). Для начала попробуйте задать полный путь для файла bubble.csv.
